# Trying to figure out influxdb with Grafana but I'm doing something wrong

Tags: influxdb, grafana

Right, so I've got a script polling folder size and putting it into influxdb

```
Measurement = "job_size"
Tag Key = "path"
Value = the size in KB
```

[image]

```
I can't seem to get this going in grafana for some reason. Could possibly be the query I'm using? Right now I'm just using SELECT * FROM job_size but it's only returning a single entry from "job_size"
```

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here ? Should I be writing it into the DB differently?

Comment: I don't see your problem here. You are inserting 1 point into influxdb and this point is shown in grafana. If you expect more points i think your problem is how you insert them into influxdb

Comment: Apologies, my screengrab only shows 1 point of data. There are in fact several thousand but for some reason only this first one is being shown. It's no doubt my query I'm using but I can't seem to figure out what I should be using.

Comment: Do you tried field(value) instead of field(*) ?

Comment: I've tried both but still no go. http://imgur.com/a/rcZ5C

Comment: Also, under "path" I can indeed see all the folders. http://imgur.com/a/GXLMs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem with the following steps. I hope this helps you to detect where you are doing something wrong.

Insert your data into influxdb

I did a quick test by creating a new db and inserted some points via line protocol:

```
influx
CREATE DATABASE stackoverflow_test
USE stackoverflow_test
INSERT job_size,path=test value=100000
INSERT job_size,path=test value=200000
INSERT job_size,path=test value=300000
```

Check if the data got inserted via the admin UI:

[image]

The grafana query:

[image]

You can see in my screenshot that my query works like expected. But If I change the query to use the '*' operator like you did in your screenshots I get no results. So avoid doing something like:

```
SELECT "value" 
FROM "job_size" 
WHERE "path" = '*'
```

And go with:

```
SELECT "value" 
FROM "job_size" 
WHERE "path" = 'test' 
  AND "path" = 'othertest' 
  AND ...
```

or if you want to select all path keys just go with:

```
SELECT "value" FROM "job_size"
```

Comment: Aha, ok so you've reproduced exactly my issue. The only problem is "test" has thousands of unique entries as they're all the folder paths. eg. /my/folder1, /my/folder2, /my/folder3 so I can't create a query and include all of them, otherwise it'd take me days just to create the query which is why I was using the "*" wildcard.

Comment: just dont query for any paths like I did in the screenshot -> and all possible paths will be included

Comment: All I get then is the value. What I need to show in grafana is; /my/folder1, 10000KB. /my/folder2, 1000KB

Comment: So you want to display the seperate line for every path? -> You can solve that with templating

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it :) Ok let me see what I can do with that.